# sdb freezes when trying to connect

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

I'm on OS X sierra, and the sdb (Smart Development Bridge 2.2.83) freezes at the smallest command.

I can create the server with

```
sdb start-server
```

However, `connect`, or even `devices` simply freeze.

Anybody has any idea of what could be the reason?

Comment: Check your firewall settings(stop it for some time), port blocking, try to connect keeping minimum distance. Use static ip instead of dynamic. Reset you device. Clear all log of previously connected devices.

Comment: firewall is already stopped.